# What's the difference between "grep -e" and "grep -E"

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have a file `test.txt`, in which there are some formatted phone numbers. I'm trying to use `grep` to find the lines containing a phone number.

It seems that `grep -e "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" test.txt` doesn't work and gives no results. But `grep -E "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" test.txt`works. So I wonder what's the difference between these 2 options.

According to `man grep`:

> -E, --extended-regexp
>                Interpret pattern as an extended regular expression (i.e. force
>                grep to behave as egrep).
>
> -e pattern, --regexp=pattern
>                Specify a pattern used during the search of the input: an input
>                line is selected if it matches any of the specified patterns.
>                This option is most useful when multiple -e options are used to
>                specify multiple patterns, or when a pattern begins with a dash
>                (`-').

But I don't quite understand it. What is an extended regex?

Comment: [`man re_format(7)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format&sektion=7)

Comment: Take a look at unix.stackexchange for these types of questions. This is, in fact, a duplicate of: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50512/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-e-and-grep-e-option

Comment: @jwd: or Stack Overflow; or Apple, or Ubuntu, or ... it is perfectly on topic here.

Comment: Well @JonathanLeffler actually not really on Apple or Ubuntu, I would argue. It is phrased so as to be relevant here, because a specific example was given, framing it as a 'programming' question as opposed to a purely technical UNIX question.

Of course, the system on which @user2440712 (man I wish they would think of real usernames) is running this also affects the answer somewhat, since different versions of `grep` abound.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you mentioned, `grep -E` is for extended regular expressions <strike>whereas `-e` is for basic regular expressions</strike>. From the man page:

EDIT: As Jonathan pointed out below, `grep -e` "specifies that the following argument is (one of) the regular expression(s) to be matched."

> #### Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
>
> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`, and `)` lose
>          their  special  meaning;  instead use the backslashed versions `\?`, `\+`, `\{`,
>          `\|`, `\(`, and `\)`.
>
> Traditional `egrep` did not support the `{`  meta-character,  and  some  `egrep`
>          implementations  support `\{` instead, so portable scripts should avoid `{` in
>          `grep -E` patterns and should use `[{]` to match a literal `{`.
>
> GNU `grep -E` attempts to support traditional usage by assuming  that `{`  is
>          not special if it would be the start of an invalid interval specification.
>          For example, the  command  `grep -E '{1'`  searches  for  the  two-character
>          string  `{1`  instead of reporting a syntax error in the regular expression.
>          POSIX.2 allows this behavior as an extension, but portable scripts  should
>          avoid it.

But man pages are pretty terse, so for further info, check out this link:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html

The part of the manpage regarding the `{` meta character though specifically talks about what you are seeing with respect to the difference.

```
grep -e "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
```

won't work because it is not treating the `{` character as you expect.  Whereas

```
grep -E "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
```

does because that is the extended grep version — or the `egrep` version for example.

Comment: `-E` is for extended regular expressions, formerly provided by `egrep`, but `-e` is not for basic regular expressions; it simply specifies that the following argument is (one of) the regular expression(s) to be matched.

Comment: Ahh, it took over a day of answers to finally get over the comment reputation hurdle, thanks for the upvote :)  Yes - exactly as Jonathan Leffler said.  I'm updating the answer there accordingly... thanks!

Comment: Hey Jonathan, not sure if you're watching, but as I'm pretty new to SO I just wanted to make sure I was following the correct protocol  with respect to revisions, I notice you made some.  Do I need to do anything on my part to accept them or are they automatically applied (ah -looks like they automatically applied - nevermind that Q.)?  In any case, thanks for the edits!  And for folks reading, check out Jonathan's answer please.

Comment: People with enough reputation (2000 or more; see the [FAQ] generally and [Privileges/Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) specifically) can edit questions and answers without going through a formal review process. People with less privilege can edit a question or answer, but it goes through a review process and 3 people must approve it. You can always make another edit so that your ID appears in the edited column if you disagree with any of the changes I made, or want to elaborate your answer. But there's nothing you have to do. If you disagree, you may be able to rollback changes.

Comment: I see, thank you - that sounds completely reasonable.  As for these edits, they look perfectly fine to me, thanks again Jonathan!

Comment: In the current form, the two command lines for `-e` and `-E` look so similar that an unknowing reader might assume that `-e` and `-E` have a similar effect. The command with the `-E` should better be written as `grep -E -e "..."`, for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple test:

```
$ cat file
apple is a fruit
so is orange
but onion is not

$ grep -e 'but' -e 'fruit' file #Allows you to pass multiple patterns explicitly
apple is a fruit
but onion is not

$ grep -E 'is (a|not)' file #Allows you to use extended regular expressions like ?, +, | etc
apple is a fruit
but onion is not
```

Answer (score 2):

The `-e` option to [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) simply says that the following argument is the regular expression.  Thus:

```
grep -e 'some.*thing' -r -l .
```

looks for `some` followed by `thing` on a line in all the files in the current directory and all its sub-directories.  The same could be achieved by:

```
grep -r -l 'some.*thing' .
```

(On Linux, the situation is confused by the behaviour of GNU `getopt()` which, unless you set POSIXLY_CORRECT in the environment, permutes options, so you could also run:

```
grep 'some.*thing' -r -l .
```

and get the same result.  Under POSIX and other systems not using GNU `getopt()`, options need to precede arguments, and the `grep` would look for a file called `-r` and another called `-l`.)

The `-E` option changes the regular expressions from ['basic' to 'extended'](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).  It can be used with `-e`:

```
grep    -e "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" test.txt
grep -E -e "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" test.txt
```

The ERE option means the same regular expressions, more or less, as used to be recognized by the [`egrep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcuix.html) command, which is no longer a part of POSIX (having been replaced by `grep -E`, and `fgrep` by `grep -F`).