# What's equation of `grep -Ern` in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I like to search string in all files with command `grep -Ern` on Bash, but what's equation on Windows PowerShell?

[image]

I've read alot about `Select-String` but I can't make it work as I expect, how should I write the params?

Comment: `gci -file -rec | sls 'Vue'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-Ern` option [stands for](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)

- Interpret PATTERNS(In this case `Vue`) as extended regular expressions(`-E`)
- Read all files under each directory, recursively(`-r`)
- Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number
  within its input file.(`-n`)

In PowerShell, You can construct the same pattern using the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1) and [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1) Cmdlets

```
Get-ChildItem -path $your_path -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "pattern"
```

- `-Recurse` option is to get the items in the specified locations and in all child items of the locations.(equivalent to `-r` for grep)
- `Select-String` automatically treat `-Pattern "pattern"` as regular expression(equivalent to `-E` for grep)
- By default, `Select-String` finds the first match in each line and, for each match, it displays the file name, line number, and all text in the line containing the match(equivalent to `-n` for grep)

Comment: wow I didn't know that about unix grep `In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning` https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130319/6654942